# Should work as a lab assistant be listed under work experience on a CV when applying for a Masters in computer science?

Tags: cv

I'm preparing my CV for applying to a MSc program in a specific Computer Science field. In the section of "Working experience" I've written about my work placement and the main job I've had the past few years (both are related with my field of studies). However, in addition to them, I was a lab assistant in my department for a whole semester. My question is, should I also mention this as a working experience? If not, what is the best way to include it to my CV?

Comment: Lab teaching assistant? Lab research assistant? What did you do?

Comment: My job was to stay for a few hours per day in the lab (since I was working on my own projects too), making sure that any student who wanted to work would have access to the necessary equipment. I was helping them setting up anything they needed (boards, instruments etc), solving minor issues with their projects, and in general I've had to keep an eye on the whole situation while the professor was away.

Comment: Your lab job sounds like a Lab teaching assistant to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you could include 'lab teaching assistant', but a research assistant would be of a better significance to include in an academic CV. If you do have other occupation to add over the years, you might not need add this one.

Comment: So, if it is to be included, it would be definitely as previous occupation, right?

Comment: Well, six months of professional research experience would be better to showcase than that of lab teaching. Personally I'd avoid it if I had better things to show.